# LEFT JOIN between two mySQL JSON Datastore queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have two queries that work to retrieve data from a mySQL JSON Datastore fieldtype.  The trick is I need to somehow LEFT JOIN them, and the typical relational-database method doesn't seem to work.

The two queries I need to somehow join are:

```
SELECT controllist.id FROM profiles, JSON_TABLE(json_data,
    '$.profile.imports[0].include."id-selectors"[*]' COLUMNS (
        id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$."control-id"')
    ) controllist
```

which returns:

```
id  

ac-1

ac-2

ac-3

ac-7

ac-8

ac-14

ac-17

ac-18

ac-19

ac-20

ac-22

at-1

at-2

at-3

at-4

au-1

au-2

au-3

au-4

au-5

au-6

au-8

au-9

au-11

au-12

ca-1

ca-2

ca-3

ca-5
```

... etc

and

```
SELECT grouplist.id, grouplist.title FROM oscal_rev5, JSON_TABLE(json_data, 
    '$.catalog.groups[*].controls[*]' COLUMNS (
        id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$.id',class VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.class',
        title VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.title')
    ) grouplist
```

which returns:

```
ac-1    Policy and Procedures

ac-2    Account Management

ac-3    Access Enforcement

ac-4    Information Flow Enforcement

ac-5    Separation of Duties

ac-6    Least Privilege

ac-7    Unsuccessful Logon Attempts

ac-8    System Use Notification

ac-9    Previous Logon Notification

ac-10   Concurrent Session Control

ac-11   Device Lock

ac-12   Session Termination

ac-13   Supervision and Review — Access Control

ac-14   Permitted Actions Without Identification or Authen...

ac-15   Automated Marking

ac-16   Security and Privacy Attributes

ac-17   Remote Access

ac-18   Wireless Access

ac-19   Access Control for Mobile Devices

ac-20   Use of External Systems

ac-21   Information Sharing

ac-22   Publicly Accessible Content

ac-23   Data Mining Protection

ac-24   Access Control Decisions

ac-25   Reference Monitor
```

...etc

I basically want to map the id's that come from the first query, with the titles that come from the second query.

something like

```
SELECT controllist.id, grouplist.title FROM profiles, JSON_TABLE(json_data, 
    '$.profile.imports[0].include."id-selectors"[*]' COLUMNS (
        id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$."control-id"')
    ) controllist 
LEFT JOIN on controllist.id = (
    SELECT grouplist.id, grouplist.title FROM oscal_rev5, JSON_TABLE(json_data, 
        '$.catalog.groups[*].controls[*]' COLUMNS (
            id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$.id',
            class VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.class',
            title VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.title')) grouplist)
```

It's not clear to me if it's a requirement that I used "JSON_TABLE" vs. just "EXTRACT" to accomplish this type of joining.  But I suspect I'm way off-base with the joining process for JSON-field-types.

If you wish to install the data via SQL to see what I mean or to help experiment, it can be installed via:

This SQL script: https://implerus.com/st_overflow/profile.sql

And then install this SQL script: https://implerus.com/st_overflow/oscal_rev5.sql

Comment: I don't want to download stuff. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t2.title from (SELECT controllist.id FROM profiles, JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.profile.imports[0].include.\"id-selectors\"[*]' COLUMNS (id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$.\"control-id\"')) controllist) t1, (SELECT grouplist.id, grouplist.title FROM oscal_rev5, JSON_TABLE(json_data, '$.catalog.groups[*].controls[*]' COLUMNS (id VARCHAR(140) PATH '$.id',class VARCHAR(20) PATH '$.class',title VARCHAR(80) PATH '$.title')) grouplist) t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id
```

Found the answer!  The trick was to not use a JOIN at all, but instead just use mySQL's native WHERE clause to identify which id's in the 2nd query to use based on the id's from the first query.